# How to manage multiple timers to control various elements of Unity game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

My end goal is to have a tile game with Home tile and surrounding tiles- character moves to highlighted square and back to home square at the speed in which the game is presented. I am trying to design a game with few speed modes. 
Two Instances being-

1. *HomeTile* highlighted then *Tile 3* (highlighted for x seconds) then
   *HomeTile* then *Tile 8* (highlighted for x seconds) then *HomeTile*.... so
   on. The x seconds can be increased or decreased by a UI slider. Points are given as the charachter enters the correct highlighted tile.
2. *HomeTile* highlighted then *Tile 3* (highlighted for x seconds) &
   character needs to be on this tile for y seconds to get point then
   *HomeTile* highlighted then *Tile 8* (highlighted for x seconds) and character
   stays for y seconds for point then *HomeTile*... and so on... Again speed
   is controlled by UI slider.

> y= 80% of x seconds.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MultiDirection_short : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider speedSlider;
    public int scoreValue;
    public static bool onTargetFlag = false; // flag to indicate character on target
    public static bool failedTargetReachFlag = false; // flag to indicate character did not reach the target

    public int currentRowNumber;
    public int randomNumber;

    private Double elapsedTime;
    public static float timeLefts;
    public float timeBeforeChange;

    private static TimeSpan time1, time2, homeTime, dwellTime, requiredDwellTime;
    private DateTime time12, startTime, dwellTimeStart;
    private bool homeSquareLit = true; // To indicate if the home Tile is on.
    private bool targetTile = false; //to indicate if any of the target tiles are on.

    void Start()
    {
        startTime = DateTime.Now; // time declared at the start of the program. This is valid for first iteration. 
    }

    void Update()
    {
        timeBeforeChange = Scaler.speedPres;
        time2 = new TimeSpan(0, 0, (int)timeBeforeChange);
        Debug.Log("TimeBeforeChange: " + (int)timeBeforeChange);
        homeTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        Debug.Log("t2/2=" + time2.Seconds / 2);

        elapsedTime = (timeLefts % 60) - DateTime.Now.Second;
        time12 = DateTime.Now; // the current time

        TimeSpan time1 = time12 - startTime;
        Debug.Log("Time1: " + time1);

        if (gameManager.Instance.Play)
        {
            if (!gameManager.Instance.Paused)
            {
                Scaler.speedPres = speedSlider.value;  // to ensure the values dont change randomly before the play button is pressed. 
            }
        }

        if (gameManager.Instance.Paused)
        {
            Scaler.speedPres = speedSlider.value;  // to ensure the values dont change randomly before the play button is pressed. 
            randomNumber = 0;

            //highlight the home square and make everything else white
            HomeTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
            FrontLeftTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;
            FrontRightTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;
        }

        if ((time1 > homeTime) && (homeSquareLit)) // TARGET SQUARE lit
        {
            randomNumber = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10);

            //Defining the conditions in which the squares light up- EACH CASE per square
            switch ((randomNumber))
            {
                case 1:
                    FrontLeftTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;//1 
                    HomeTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;//0
                    FrontRightTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;//4

                    break;
                case 2:
                    FrontRightTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;//2
                    HomeTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;//0 
                    FrontLeftTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;//3

                    break;

                default:
                    targetTile = false;
                    homeSquareLit = false;
                    break;
            }
            startTime = time12;
            Debug.Log("startTime: " + startTime);

        }

        if ((time1 > time2) && (!homeSquareLit)) // HOME SQUARE BLOCK
        {
            Debug.Log("inside home square block, randNum_ now:  " + randomNumber);

            switch ((randomNumber))
            {
                case 1:

                    HomeTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
                    FrontLeftTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;//3
                    FrontRightTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;//4
                    break;

                case 2:

                    HomeTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
                    FrontLeftTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;//3
                    FrontRightTile.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;//4
                default:
                    break;
            }
            startTime = time12;
        }
    }

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    dwellTimeStart = DateTime.Now;
    requiredDwellTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    DateTime requiredDwellTime = 1.5f;
    if ((dwellTimeStart.Second > requiredDwellTime.Seconds)) // TARGET SQUARE lit
    {//trigger or change color of tile as above.
}
```

So for the First Scenario- This code works fine as is.. However when I reduce the time on the slider below 2 seconds then the the half equals 0 as int. Then the game stops working with the if statements... Or if statements are removed then it works so fast that it looks like its flickering between the targets.

Am I supposed to use a different timer? AM i mistakenly taking update time?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static float timeLefts;
public float timeBeforeChange;
private static TimeSpan time1, time2, homeTime, dwellTime, requiredDwellTime;
private DateTime time12, startTime, dwellTimeStart;
```

Oh geezus. You have TEN timer values you're keeping track of inside a *single class*. This is Not The Way To Go.

You have two options:

1. Custom object(s) that you can instantiate and hold their time value and perform whatever-task as needed, you store these in a list that you update every frame.
2. [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html), where you say "execute this function as a coroutine" and inside that function you can do things like `yield return new WaitForSeconds(5)` to make the execution of that function pause for 5 seconds (or however long).

Comment: Thank you.  @Draco18s. Yes I am being inefficient! I guess I am putting too many things in one class?

Could you explain how I can do option 1? To use for different modes and still run the game ? 

2. I am giving this a shot based on examples and will let you know...

Comment: its going to be pretty specific for your use-case, but the general idea is to have some kind of common structure that all of your timed-things have and encapsulate it in an abstract class or an interface, which you then extend and implement specific functionality for.